# How do I access a dictionary database in Python Tkinter for usernames and passwords?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have been working on a login screen for a typing program using Python Tkinter, and I want to use a database to hold the information for multiple users in a dictionary format, where the key is the username and the value of the key is its password. I then have two buttons, one is to change the password of an entered username and another as a login button. This is the code that I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import dbm

db=dbm.open('M:\\Python\\Typing Program\\Dictionary.db','c')
db['Mistap']='steefjabz'

class TypingLogin(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    container=tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (LoginScreen,TestScreen):
        frame=F(container, self)
        self.frames[F]=frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.ShowFrame(LoginScreen)

def ShowFrame(self, cont):

    frame=self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()

class LoginScreen(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    self.controller=controller
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    self.usernamelabel=tk.Label(self, text="Username")
    self.passwordlabel=tk.Label(self, text="Password")

    self.usernameentry=tk.Entry(self)
    self.passwordentry=tk.Entry(self, show="*")

    self.usernamelabel.grid(row=0, sticky="e")
    self.passwordlabel.grid(row=1, sticky="e")
    self.usernameentry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.passwordentry.grid(row=1, column=1)

    self.loginbutton=tk.Button(self, text="Change Password", command=self.LoginButtonClicked)#When Lesson select screen is made, put navigating command here
    self.loginbutton2=tk.Button(self, text="Login")

    self.loginbutton.grid(row=2, column=1)
    self.loginbutton2.grid(row=3, column=1)

    self.pack()

def LoginButtonClicked(self):
    global db

    username=self.usernameentry.get()
    password=self.passwordentry.get()
    if username in db and password==db[username]:
        self.controller.show_frame(TestScreen)
    else:
        tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect Login details")

class TestScreen(tk.Frame,tk.Toplevel):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.label=tk.Label(self, text="Old Password")
    self.label2=tk.Label(self, text="New Password")
    self.label3=tk.Label(self, text="Confirm Password")

    self.entry=tk.Entry(self, show="*")
    self.entry2=tk.Entry(self, show="*")
    self.entry3=tk.Entry(self, show="*")

    self.label.grid(row=0, sticky="e")
    self.label2.grid(row=1, sticky="e")
    self.label3.grid(row=2, sticky="e")
    self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    self.entry3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    self.changebutton=tk.Button(self, text="Change", command=self.ChangePassword)#When Lesson select screen is made, put navigating command here
    self.changebutton.grid(row=3, column=1)

def ChangePassword(self):
    global db,username
    if self.entry.get()==db[Username] and self.entry2.get()==self.entry3.get():
        db[Username]=self.entry2.get()
    elif self.entry.get()==db[Username] and self.entry2.get()!=self.entry3.get():
        tm.showerror("Password Error", "New Password does not match Confirm Password")
    else:
        tm.showerror("Password error", "Incorrect Password")


app = TypingLogin()
app.mainloop()
```

Please let me know if you find the problems with this program and/or if it is impossible to just do with Python and Tkinter.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well for starters your `TestScreen` inherits from both `tk.Frame` and `tk.Toplevel` which doesn't make any sense, I think you _just_ want it to be a `Toplevel`.

Comment: second `frame.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="nsew")` puts both frames in the same space, you probably want to use `enumerate` to get some index so that you place them in separate places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the keys and values in the database are being converted to `bytes` objects:

```
db=dbm.open('M:\\Python\\Typing Program\\Dictionary.db','c')
db['Mistap']='steefjabz'
print(dict(db))

#output:  notice the b'' prefix
{b'Mistap': b'steefjabz'}
```

I added `.encode()` to convert the strings from the entry to `bytes` like this:

```
    username=self.usernameentry.get().encode()
    password=self.passwordentry.get().encode()
```

and instead of saying I had invalid credentials raised an error for having no attribute called `show_frame` (the method is defined as `ShowFrame`)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now except for an error when I press the "Change" button on the Change Password screen. In the `ChangePassword` function, it is not recognizing `username` as a global variable. I have already fixed the capitalization.

Comment: thats because `username` is not a global variable, it is local to `LoginButtonClicked`, unless you meant to add `global username` there too.

Comment: @JamesSchanbacher, see above comment. Also btw you don't need the global keyword to **use** global variables (`tk` is a global variable and nearly all of your functions use it) You will only need the `global` statement if you _directly assign a variable_ (like `username = ...`) you don't even need it to _modify_ global variables so you don't need `global db` anywhere.